# Removing an item from itemsource for UI only

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, enums, markup-extensions

I have a combobox binded with an Enum, My Enum has None or NA values which are required at Model level but those values are irrelevant to user at UI level.I dont want to show them to user.I also dont want to use a separate Enum for viewmodel and view.So I made a markup extension which will remove None or NA from item source.Here is my code`

```
 public sealed class EnumBindingHelper : MarkupExtension
{

    private readonly Type _enumType;

    public EnumBindingHelper(Type enumType)
    {
        _enumType = enumType;

    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {

        var  arr= Enum.GetValues(_enumType);

        var list = (from object item in arr select item.ToString()).ToList();

        list.RemoveAll(x => x.Equals("None") || x.Equals("NA") || x.Equals("NONE") || x.Equals("Na"));

         return list;
    }
}
```

My view binding is

```
 <ComboBox ItemsSource="{helpers:EnumBindingHelper {x:Type MyEnum}}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedValue,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Its working fine in UI ,I dont see NA and none values in combobox ,but the selected item in UI is always empty when I launch application.

MY enum is

```
MyEnum
{
   value1=0,
   value2=1,
   value3=2,
   None=4

}
```

Iam also setting SelectedValue=value1 in my viewmodel code.
Can anybody explain why this is happening and how can I solve this.I want normal behaviour like selected item should be as per binding or first item if selected item is null.

Comment: It is a reference problem. If you want to set the selected value from the viewmodel, you have get the value you want from the ItemSource. Otherwise it will always be null

Comment: I can think of workarounds.. but i would try setting issynchronizedwithcurrentitem="True"
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library  /system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.issynchronizedwithcurrentitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MarkupExtension should return the filtered enum values instead of strings:

```
private static readonly string[] exclude =
    new string[] { "None", "NONE", "Na", "NA" };

public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    return Enum.GetValues(_enumType).Cast<object>()
        .Where(e => !exclude.Contains(e.ToString())).ToList();
}
```